# Linux: schedule command at a specific, different predetermined time every day

Tags: mysql, linux, job-scheduling, ubuntu-server

I have to run a command every day at a different time. The times are known in advance and saved in a MySQL database in the familiar `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format.

**What I thought of:**

1. `cron` schedule the job for the exact time the first day, then make the script itself modify the `crontab` entry with the correct time for the next day.
2. `cron` scheduling the job at *approximately* the right time, then make it read the *exact* time from the database and sleep until then.
3. `cron` schedule the job execution every minute, and leave it to the script to determine whether the current date/time corresponds to the right execution time; proceded if it is, exit if not.
4. `at` submit the job the first day with `at`, then make it read the next day's time from the database and resubmit itself for then with `at`.

**Additional info:**

The command is a PHP script that composes the message of the day and sends it to all users registered to the website. I can consider other technologies if they solve this problem better. I would like to retain the ability of rebooting the server (outside of the intended execution hour) without worrying too much about jobs getting lost, therefore solutions `1.` and `3.` look better under this aspect. I'm starting with two commands to be run at two different times of the day, but I could soon end up with dozens more of similar jobs to be scheduled at different times every day, so I would prefer to avoid clutter as much as possible. I'd probably go with option `3` at this point.

**The question(s):**
Is there a better / preferred / established way of accomplishing this task? Solutions other that those mentioned above are welcome. What are the main drawbacks (of your recommended solution) I should be aware of?

Comment: There is no cron job to run a script the exact minute, Most small size you will get is hour.  The hour starts when the system boots and it repeats since then. You should look for `anacron` or similar.

Comment: @suleiman I thought that `cron` can run commands at exactly the specified time, with a precision of one minute. Why would you recommend `anacron` instead? I read that "Anacron is the cron for desktops and laptops, and does not expect the system to be running 24 x 7 like a server." and I'm running a server, which is usually up 24x7.

Comment: @suleiman I do believe you are wrong in saying this. 

The minimum interval is one minute and you can specify precise time of the day, so, also the consideration about the way it starts counting the hours is wrong.

Comment: my corn folders are: `/etc/cron.daily cron.hourly cron.monthly and cron.weekly` nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using solution `3.` above and am quite satisfied with it so far.

All the logic is in the `.php` file, which is responsible to:

1. save the current date/time in a variable (e.g. `$now`)
2. perform any considerations on it
3. scan the database in search of a matching date/time

This actually allows for a reasonable degree of flexibility:

1. I can choose not to run any commands if a certain semaphore file exists:

   ```
   if (file_exists($filename)) {exit;}
   ```
2. I can set parameters in an option file enabling e.g. debug or test modes:

   ```
   include parameters.php
   if ($debug === true) {error_reporting(E_ALL);}
   ```
3. I can avoid bothering users if it is, let's say, new year's day:

   ```
   if (date('m-d') == '01-01') {exit;}
   ```
4. I can introduce delays based on custom logic:

   ```
   if (date('w', strtotime($now)) === '0') {$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($now . ' +15 minutes'));}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you need to build your custom application for implementing the logic you want to implement.

Eventually you can use the cron system to start the process or to make sure that the process is running (in case it died or it was killed).

In your place what I would do, is to write a custom PHP program (or python or you name it) that performs the following:

- Opens a connection to DB
- Checks when the next execution is scheduled
- Calculates if it is time to run
- if not, it sleeps for X seconds (this depends on your preference)
- it it is time to run, it performs its duty
- sleeps again, and the loop begins

An alternative would be to check the every time the execution schedule, to check for changes in the schedule.

Another one would be read once and sleep until the execution time, but in this other case you would not catch changes in the schedule

This all depends on you, all in the all the program is an extremely easy one

Comment: you also can look if a execution time is set via the cron script an then schedule the run via the **at** command and remove/ delete the starttime in the database. if the cronjob finds a new start time they do it again. https://linux.die.net/man/1/at

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please illustrate any advantages of this solution over option `3.` above. It does add a layer of complexity, in the form of another script that should be monitored and kept running all the time. I believe it's best to rely on the existing scheduled instead of implementing my own unless there are clear advantages. On a different note, I always thought of PHP as unsuited for neverending tasks, compared to other technologies; please advise otherwise.

Comment: @BerndBuffen what you mention is a nice addition to the answer I'll certainly consider it **if** I go down the route of implementing my own scheduler. Instead of deleting the record, it could be marked as executed.